# Cómo colorear los municipios de un estado de la república mexicana usando el paquete "leaflet" en R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Busco colorear los municipios de un estado de la república basándome en el código de https://rpubs.com/walkerke/leaflet_choropleth , el problema reside en que en el ejemplo colorean todos los estados de la república en base al indicador de PIB per cápita y yo no busco eso.

Comment: Podrías añadir lo que tu has intentado? Que problemas has tenido? Si te aparece algun error, cual es ese error.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que buscas y __qué estás haciendo para lograrlo__? Por favor agrega un __[mcve]__ para comprender tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El coloreado se puede hacer en base a cualquier dato que tengas de cada estado. En el ejemplo que pasaste, se recupera un "shapefile" que además de la info de los polígonos para dibujar el mapa, tiene algunos indicadores del pais, de hecho se  está usando el del PIB (acá en la Argentina le decimos PBI) por estado. El truco podría ser agregarle al `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`luego de importado, la columna que deseemos con los valores para cada estado. Te paso el mismo ejemplo pero agregando una columna con información "random" y luego graficamos la misma.

```
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)

tmp <- tempdir()
url <- "http://personal.tcu.edu/kylewalker/data/mexico.zip"
file <- basename(url)

download.file(url, file)

unzip(file, exdir = tmp)
mexico <- readOGR(dsn = tmp, layer = "mexico", encoding = "UTF-8")

# Creo una columna nueva con datos random ##################################
mexico@data$random <- 1:nrow(mexico@data)
mexico@data$random <- sample(1000000, size = nrow(mexico@data), replace = TRUE)
############################################################################


pal <- colorQuantile("YlGn", NULL, n = 5)

state_popup <- paste0("<strong>Estado: </strong>", 
                      mexico$name, 
                      "<br><strong>Valores random para cada estado: </strong>", 
                      mexico$random)

leaflet(data = mexico) %>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
    addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(random), 
                fillOpacity = 0.8, 
                color = "#BDBDC3", 
                weight = 1, 
                popup = state_popup)
```

**Nota Importante**: Si vamos a tocar la parte de los datos del `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` para agregarle una columna, debemos mantener el orden original, sino se corre el riesgo que se "desordenen" los estados, y que cambien de nombre.

Comment: gracias!, ya lo pude resolver

Answer (score 1):

### R leaflet: Mapas de los estados mexicanos

No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. ¿Quieres dar un color único a cada municipio?
Aquí te muestro dos maneras distintas de agregar colores a los municipios de México. Para esto he utilizado los archivo JSON de INEGI, pero con una pequeña modificación. Comparto el link de mi drive donde se encuentran los archivos modificados [colección json México.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2uk4BKdSI3iXzJfWDNoY1k3bHM?usp=sharing) El archivo "Munxentidad1.json" es el mapa de Aguascalientes, así pues el número antes del punto indica el código del estado. Por otra parte usarlo con Shiny seria relativamente sencillo si tienes experiencia, te recomiendo revisar el paquete [highcharter.](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/)

#### Utilizando jsonlite

A continuación el código necesario para generar un mapa   del estado de Baja California, México.

```
   #Mapa de un estado con jsonlite y addGeoJSON
library(leaflet)
library(jsonlite)
#Leer datos
prub<-readLines("convertgsone/www/Munxentidad2.json", warn = FALSE) %>%
  paste(collapse = "\n") %>%
  fromJSON(simplifyVector = FALSE)

# Obtener los codigos del municipio
mun_code <- sapply(prub$features, function(feat) {
  feat$properties$mun_code[[1]]
})

#crear una funcion de color de mun_code
pal<-colorQuantile("Greens",mun_code)

#Estilo predeterminado
prub$style = list(
  weight = 1,
  color = "black",
  opacity = 1,
  fillOpacity = 1
)

# Agregar el color properties$style la cada  feature
prub$features <- lapply(prub$features, function(feat) {
  feat$properties$style <- list(
    fillColor = pal(feat$properties$mun_code[[1]])
  )
  feat
})

# crear mapa
leaflet() %>% setView(lng = -102.583, lat = 23.833, zoom = 4.5) %>%
  addTiles() %>% addGeoJSON(prub,noClip=TRUE)%>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = mun_code, opacity = 1)
```

Así se ve el resultado,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Utilizando geojsonio

Ahora haré un mapa del estado de Quintana Roo , México.

```
#Mapa de un estado con el paquete geojsonio y addPolygons
library(geojsonio)
#Leer los poligonos

entidad23 <- geojson_read("convertgsone/www/Munxentidad23.json",
                                      what = "sp")
#Creaf funcion de color

pal <- colorNumeric("viridis", NULL)


#Agregar un indice (valor aleatorio) para colorear
entidad23@data$indice<-rnorm(length(entidad23@data$mun_code1),10,4)

#Crear mapa
leaflet(entidad23) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.3, fillOpacity = 1,
              fillColor = ~pal(indice),
              label = ~paste0(mun_name, ": ", formatC(indice, big.mark = ","))) %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~indice, opacity = 1.0,
            labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x) round(x)))
```

Este es el mapa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Conclusiones

- Si se desea utilizar con shiny la segunda opción es mas interactiva.