# Crear mapa en R con ggmap

Tags: r, map, leaflet

Tengo una base de datos que cada que se genera una incidencia crea una nueva entrada, uno de los parámetros que tengo es latitud y longitud. Quiero crear un código en R que tome esos valores de latitud y longitud y genere un mapa de México que dibuje en tonos de color (estilo chloropleth) las ocurrencias agrupadas, ed decir si tuve en un estado 10 ocurrencias y en otro 5 pintar esos estados de distintos colores.

Estuve investigando y todo lo que encuentro utiliza shapefiles que ya tienen información precargada.

Alguien podría guiarme a por dónde empezar y cómo manipular mis datos?

Answer (score 1):

Hace un tiempo respondí [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/69171/c%C3%B3mo-colorear-los-municipios-de-un-estado-de-la-rep%C3%BAblica-mexicana-usando-el-paq/69200#69200), la solución a la tuya es bastante parecida. Partimos de un "shapefile" que no es más que un conjunto de puntos que describen polígonos para cada estado, luego necesitamos un conjunto de números para cada uno de estos estado, según dicho número será el color.

En tu caso, imagino que tienes un lista de coordenadas (latitud/longitud) que señalan cada ubicación geográfica, la cual corresponderá a un estado. Según las cantidades de estos puntos será el color en el mapa. Por lo que lo esencial es como relacionar estos puntos con cada estado.

Veamos paso a paso como resolver esto

#### Obtener un "shapefile" correspondiente al país

Voy a usar el mismo que en la pregunta anterior, pero puedes buscar cualquier otro, por ejemplo los de [arcgis](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ac9041c51b5c49c683fbfec61dc03ba8) deberían funcionar igual

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)

tmp <- tempdir()
url <- "http://personal.tcu.edu/kylewalker/data/mexico.zip"
file <- basename(url)

download.file(url, file)

unzip(file, exdir = tmp)
mexico <- readOGR(dsn = tmp, layer = "mexico", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Cargamos los tres paquetes requeridos:

- rgdal
- sp
- leaflet

Luego descargamos el "shapefile" descomprimimos y leemos el archivo, finalizamos con un objeto (`mexico`) del tipo `"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"`.

#### Generar una serie de suficientes puntos aleatorios

Como no has publicado un ejemplo de los datos, voy a generar uno. La idea es bien sencilla, generar puntos aleatorios dentro del rectangulo completo del mapa, esto lo obtienes usando `mexico@bbox`. Muchos de los puntos caerán en el mar o fuera del territorio mexicano, es decir no dentro en un estado, por lo que hay que generar una buena cantidad para asegurarnos de tener algún ejemplo:

```
pts <- data.frame(x=runif(100000, mexico@bbox[1,],mexico@bbox[3]), 
                  y=runif(100000, mexico@bbox[2,],mexico@bbox[4])
                 )
```

en `pts` tenemos una lista de 100.000 puntos, ahora lo que falta y es lo que deberías hacer a partir de tu lista real de puntos es:

#### Relacionar puntos con estados

```
coordinates(pts) <- ~x+y  # pts needs to be a data.frame for this to work
proj4string(pts) <- proj4string(mexico)
estados <- over(pts, mexico)$id      # matching de las coordenadas con los estados

estados <- estados[!is.na(estados)]  # Borramos Na (puntos fuera de cualquier estado)
mexico@data$random <- as.integer(unlist(aggregate(estados, by=list(estados), FUN=sum)[2]))
```

Lo fundamental está en las primeras tres instrucciones, en las que terminamos "matcheando" los puntos con un `id` del estado del `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` original. Por último contamos los puntos de cada estado y agregamos esta información al `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. Si analizamos el contenido:

```
head(data.frame(id=mexico$id, estado=mexico$name, data=mexico@data$random))

  id              estado  data
1  1      Aguascalientes    39
2  2     Baja California  1170
3  3 Baja California Sur  1647
4  4            Campeche  1672
5  5             Chiapas  2840
6  6           Chihuahua 12234
```

Cada estado tiene una cantidad de puntos asociados a él, obviamente en este ejemplo los estados mas extensos tendrán más puntos, pero se entiende la idea.

Lo último será:

## Graficar usando `leaflet`

```
pal <- colorQuantile("Blues", NULL, n = 10)
state_popup <- paste0("<strong>Estado: </strong>", 
                      mexico$name, 
                      "<br><strong>Valores random para cada estado: </strong>", 
                      mexico$random)

leaflet(data = mexico) %>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
    addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(random), 
                fillOpacity = 0.8, 
                color = "#BDBDC3", 
                weight = 1, 
                popup = state_popup)
```

Finalmente obtendremos algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]