# ¿como hacer con leaflet un mapa de españa por provincias coloreadas?

Tags: r, map

estoy mirando lo de hacer mapas con leaflet y quedan muy bien, pero me lio con tantas opciones que tiene

necesito solo hacer un mapa de regiones y provincias de España. Queríamos colorear de un color las regiones autonómicas que participan en un convenio (que no son todas), y dentro de estas, resaltar con algo más de color las provincias que participan (porque algunas provincias participan y otras no)

Comment: Hola Genebrando, bienvenido. ¿Podrías incluir el código con el que has intentado resolver tu problemas hasta ahora? Idealmente también un ejemplo reproducible del problema, si no se puede al menos un ejemplo de los datos que estas utilizando. Con esa información seguramente tendrás una respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: Una pregunta ¿tiene que ser necesariamente con `leaflet`? Hay una librería relativamente nueva que se llama `sf` y facilita muchísimo hacer mapas coropléticos (coloreados de acuerdo con algún atributo de los polígonos interiores, en tu caso, formar o no formar parte del convenio). El truco de `sf` es que tiene los polígonos dentro de un `data.frame`, por lo que puedes manipular todos los elementos no polígonos con las herramientas habituales de R y luego generar el mapa con `ggplot2`. Advierto: no genera un mapa interactivo javascript como `leaflet`.

Comment: Hola mpaladino,

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Cómo colorear los municipios de un estado de la república mexicana usando el paquete "leaflet" en R shiny](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/69171/c%c3%b3mo-colorear-los-municipios-de-un-estado-de-la-rep%c3%bablica-mexicana-usando-el-paq)

Comment: Pensaba responderte, pero la respuesta sería demasiado parecida a la que ya he dado en el enlace más arriba, revisala y cualquier duda, me haces algún comentario. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un procedimiento simple para hacer un mapa coroplético de Españo coloreado en las provincias y CCAA.

Como no tengo tus datos (i.e. la lista de provincias que participan en el convenio en cuestión) me lo voy a inventar.

## Descargar los shapefiles y cargarlos como un objeto de la clase `sf`

En esta dirección https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=83d81d9336c745fd839465beab885ab7 se puede descargar un .zip con el shapefile necesario. 
Hay que descomprimirlo y ubucar la carpeta resultante como subdirectorio del proyecto en el que estamos trabajando en R. De paso le cambié el nombre a `./provincias` para facilitarme las cosas, el nombre original es largo.

Deberían estar los siguientes archivos:

Provincias_ETRS89_30N.dbf       Provincias_ETRS89_30N.sbx       Provincias_ETRS89_30N.shx
  Provincias_ETRS89_30N.prj       Provincias_ETRS89_30N.shp
  Provincias_ETRS89_30N.sbn       Provincias_ETRS89_30N.shp.xml

Es necesario tener instalada la librería `sf`. Tiene unas cuantas dependencias algunas a nivel sistema operativo. Puede complicarse un poco en Linux.

### Carga el shapefile

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse) # La vamos a usar más adelante

carto_base <- sf::read_sf("./provincias/")  #Asumiendo que está en el subdirectorio provincias de getwd()
plot(carto_base) #verificacion
```

Si todo salió bien deberías ver 5 mapas de España. Es solo para verificar que está todo en orden.

## Combinar con los datos que queremos graficar

Una de las innovaciones de `sf` es que carga los objetos cartográficos en un clase dentro de R que funciona como un `data.frame` con una columna especial (`geometry`) que contiene una lista con toda la información de la geometría de los polígonos, proyección, etc. Lo importante es que al funcionar como data.frame toda la manipulación de datos (joins con otras bases, filtrados, etc.) se puede hacer con las herramientas usuales de manipulación de datos de R. Funciona especialmente bien con `tidyverse`.

Para hacer tu mapa necesitas un `data.frame` que tenga dos caractísticas:

1. Una columna en común con los datos geográficos en `carto_base`, para poder combinarlos. Generalmente es el nombre o código numérico (mejor, menos ambiguo) de las unidades territoriales que sobre las que vas graficar. En este caso, provincias. Es mejor que el nombre de esta columna sea el mismo que la columna equivalente en los `carto_base`, ya que eso simplificará el `join`  de los datos. En el shapefile que cargué se llama `Texto` o `Código`, dependiendo si usas nombres o códigos numéricos.
2. Otra columna con los datos a partir de los cuales se va a colorear. En tu caso podrías `convenio` y tener los niveles `Sí`, `No` (o 0,1, lo que sea que las distinga). Supongo que ya tienes esos datos, deberías asegurarte de que se cumpla la condición 1.

Como no tengo los datos me los voy a inventar, asumiendo que Salamanca, Madrid y Guipúzcoa participan del convenio y las demas provincias no. Va a ser un poquito complicado porque tengo que simular los datos_a_graficar

Hago un df base con las tres provincias "participantes" y el `Sí` para el convenio:

```
datos_a_graficar <- tibble(Texto = c("Salamanca", "Madrid", "Guipúzcoa"), 
                           convenio = "Sí") #Por regla de reciclaje Sí se extiende tantas veces como el largo de Texto.
```

## Unir los datos de interés con los datos cartográficos:

Uso el método de join porque es el más habitual si ya tienes los datos_a_graficar

```
left_join(carto_base, datos_a_graficar) %>% #Aquí ya quedan unidos, solo que codigo tiene el valor NA cuando no participa en el convenio y queremos que diga explíctamente No
  mutate(convenio = ifelse(is.na(convenio), "No", convenio)) -> carto_unida # Aquí paso los NA a "No" usando dplyr. Nunca se pierden los datos geográficos!
```

## Graficar el mapa básico

Ya tengo `carto_unida` que incluye los datos geográficos y los datos del convenio. Primero el mapa más simple:

Nota: `geom_sf` aparece en `ggplot2 3.0`. Asegurarse de tener la última versión de CRAN.
  ggplot

```
ggplot(data = carto_unida, aes(fill = convenio)) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  labs (title = "Provincias que han suscripto el importante convenio", 
        caption = "Dar acá créditos por los datos y cartografía")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Graficar el mapa de la pregunta

Para hacer lo de las CCAA es un poquito más complicado, porque tu base cartográfica (las filas del objeto `sf`) son provincias. Sin embargo como hay una relación jerárquica de los datos (varias provincias una CCAA) se puede hacer. De paso le hago algunos cambios estéticos al mapa.

```
carto_base %>% 
group_by (CCAA) %>% 
mutate(convenio = ifelse(any(Texto %in% datos_a_graficar$Texto), #Si alguna provincia participante está en esta CCAA marca toda la CCAA
                         "CCAA", "No")) %>% 
mutate(convenio = ifelse(Texto %in% datos_a_graficar$Texto,      #datos_a_graficar$Text es un vector, por eso funciona el %in%
                         "Provincia", convenio)) %>%             #Marco con otro código a las provincias participantes.
mutate(convenio = factor(convenio, levels = c("Provincia", "CCAA", "No"))) %>%    #Reordeno el factor, para que se vea mejor la etiqueta
filter(CCAA != "Canarias") %>%                                   #Sólo España continental y Baleares, eliminando esta línea aparece Canarias
ggplot() +
geom_sf(aes(fill = convenio), color = "grey", size = 0.2)  +
coord_sf(datum = NA) +                                           #Elimino las coordenadas, no aportan mucho en un coroplético
theme_minimal() +                                                #Fondo blanco, mapa simple.
theme(legend.position = "top") +                                 # La leyenda arriba
scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "lightgreen", "white")) + # Se pueden cambiar los colores acá.
labs(title = "Provincias y CCAA participantes del convenio", 
     fill = "Nivel en el que participa")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puf... Fenómenal. No sólo el trabajo casi listo, sino que queda genial. Muchísimas gracias, me pongo a ello!  espero poder colaborar con otras cuestiones de R que si conozco, no conocía de este lugar hasta hace poco. Un saludo!

Comment: Que bueno que te sirva. Si es el caso podrías dar a la respuesta por aceptada. Esperamos tus contribuciones. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Perdón que me lio un poco con esto

Gracias por el interés. Voy a mirar la librería sf que no la conocía. En realidad yo no necesito un mapa interactivo así que a lo mejor me lío menos que con `leaflet`

Hasta el momento he conseguido con esto

```
mapa <- readOGR("ESP_adm/ESP_adm2.shp")

mapa$NAME_0 <- iconv(mapa$NAME_0, from="UTF-8", to="LATIN1")
mapa$NAME_1 <- iconv(mapa$NAME_1, from="UTF-8", to="LATIN1")
mapa$NAME_2 <- iconv(mapa$NAME_2, from="UTF-8", to="LATIN1")

leaflet(mapa) %>%
  addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 2, fillOpacity = 0.5)
```

hacer un mapa que dibuja las provincias. Tengo que mirar como conseguir marcar unas provincias de un color y otras de otro (en función de una columna donde marcaré con 1 o 0 por ejemplo si participan en el convenio o no)